# How to handle multiple requests using bottle-gevent?

Tags: python, bottle, cherrypy, gevent

I am developing a web service which has huge computations in the backend. Below is the code with bottle framework and "Cherrypy" server (Multi-threaded and very stable). 
But after testing it for sometime, I feel it is not servering as fast as I expected. The code using "Cherrypy" is below

```
from bottle import Bottle
import logging.handlers

logger = logging.getLogger()
logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

# Logging handler for files
file_handler = logging.handlers.TimedRotatingFileHandler("Log.log", when="midnight", interval=1,
                                                         backupCount=10000)
file_handler.setLevel(logging.INFO)

# Formatter's for logging
formatter = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s %(name)s %(levelname)s %(message)s')
file_handler.setFormatter(formatter)
# Add handlers to the logger
logger.addHandler(file_handler)


class App:

    def __init__(self, server, host, port):
        self._app = Bottle()
        self._host = host
        self._port = port
        self._server = server
        self._route()

    def start(self):
        self._app.run(server=self._server, host=self._host, port=self._port)
        logger.info("Application Started Successfully.")

    def _route(self):
        self._app.route('/hello/<name>', method="POST", callback=self.hello)

    def hello(self, name):
        print("hello ", name)
        logger.info("completed the response")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    server = App(server='cheroot', host='0.0.0.0', port=9999)
    server.start()
```

The Web Service which I am developing is called by multiple requests at the same time. The Cherrypy server is on estimate takes 40000ms seconds for the response. This is huge time . 
So I planned to use "Gevent" server (Asynchronous). But I am facing an issue that multiple threads (GREENLET) resolves same request. The code for this is as shown

```
from bottle import Bottle
import logging.handlers

from gevent import monkey
monkey.patch_all()

class App:

    def __init__(self, server, host, port):
        self._app = Bottle()
        self._host = host
        self._port = port
        self._server = server
        self._route()

    def start(self):
        self._app.run(server=self._server, host=self._host, port=self._port)
        logger.info("Application Started Successfully.")

    def _route(self):
        self._app.route('/hello/<name>', method="POST", callback=self.hello)

    def hello(self, name):
        print("hello ", name)
        logger.info("completed the response")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    server = App(server='gevent', host='0.0.0.0', port=9999)
    server.start()
```

Actual time for a single request is 9000ms, So the increse in time to 40000ms or even more some times makes me to choose gevent.

How to control the GREENLET to take a single request and send the response to the request with a minimum time while other GREENLET handling the other request from other machine?

Answer (score 1):

You might be over thinking this. You want to use the route decorators.  Each user hitting a route will be inside their own greenlet.  If you want to ensure this, you can call a function with `gevent.spawn()`

```
import gevent
from gevent import monkey, signal
monkey.patch_all()
from gevent.pywsgi import WSGIServer
from geventwebsocket.handler import WebSocketHandler
import bottle
from bottle import get, post, template, request, response
import logging.handlers
logger = logging.getLogger()
logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

# Logging handler for files
file_handler = logging.handlers.TimedRotatingFileHandler("Log.log", when="midnight", interval=1,
                                                         backupCount=10000)
file_handler.setLevel(logging.INFO)

# Formatter's for logging
formatter = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s %(name)s %(levelname)s %(message)s')
file_handler.setFormatter(formatter)
# Add handlers to the logger
logger.addHandler(file_handler)


@get('/hello/<name>')
@post('/hello/<name>')
def _hello(self, name):
    print("hello ", name)
    logger.info("completed the response")
    return "hello {}".format(name)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    botapp = bottle.app()
    server = WSGIServer(("0.0.0.0", 9999), botapp, handler_class=WebSocketHandler)
    def shutdown():
        print('Shutting down ...')
        server.stop(timeout=60)
        exit(signal.SIGTERM)
    gevent.signal(signal.SIGTERM, shutdown)
    gevent.signal(signal.SIGINT, shutdown)  # CTRL C
    logger.info("Application Started Successfully.")
    server.serve_forever()
```